# Convert string dictionnary into dictionnary format

Tags: python, json, dictionary, converters

I try to convert a string value into Dictionary format. I must respect this syntax but when I try to convert the string value into a dictionary I have a error. The json.load convert the bracket nested into a string and not into a dictionary format.

Do you have any idea to resolve this ?

```
    import json
    dict_info = "{\"strategy\" : \"" + "ok" + "\", \"aa\" : \"" + "{\"strategy\" : \"" + 
    "strg" + "\"}" + "\"}"
    json.loads(dict_info)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because here you are specifying that the value for key `aa` is a string by adding `"` before and after the value,

ie this part: **\"** `" + "{\"strategy\" : \"" +  "strg" + "\"}" + "` **\"**

If you remove those the code should work, here

**Code**:

```py
import json
dict_info = "{\"strategy\" : \"" + "ok" + "\", \"aa\" : " + "{\"strategy\" : \"" + "strg" + "\"}" + "}"
d = json.loads(dict_info)
print(d)
print(d['aa'])
```

**Output**:

```
{'strategy': 'ok', 'aa': {'strategy': 'strg'}}
{'strategy': 'strg'}
```

Comment: hello Abhi_J, thank you for your support !

Comment: @FloCp, if you think that the answer was helpful, you should accept it, so that future programmers will see and benefit from it

Comment: Hello, yes it's done. But we must to wait 8 min to accept the answer